# How are the two definitions of graph state mathematically equivalent?

Tags: graph-states

There are at least two definitions of Graph State, two of them are shown in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_state#Formal_definition). The first definition is via quantum states, while the second one is from the point of view of the stabilizer group. How are the two definitions mathematically equivalent?

Comment: I answered the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4204716/graph-states-two-equivalent-definitions/4214989#4214989).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first definition says the nodes start in the $|+\rangle$ state and then you apply a CZ for each edge.

The $|+\rangle$ state's stabilizer is $X$. When you conjugate an $X$ observable by a CZ operation, you end up with $X \otimes Z$. When you conjugate a $Z$ observable by a CZ you just get the $Z$ unchanged. This means propagating the $X$ stabilizer forward through time, through the CZs, kicks out a $Z$ on the other side of each CZ. So you end up with a stabilizer that's $X$ on the node times $Z$ on each neighbor. That's the second definition.